# Using custom setting for email list

Tags: developer

I'm trying to use a custom setting to store email addresses to be used when sending out an Excel file of an Apex job that deactivates users and I'm not exactly sure how to do so. I setup a custom setting as a string and put 'avalidemailaddress@email.com' but I keep getting "Method does not exist or incorrect signature" error.

Currently, my code is

```
Batch_Settings__c batchSettings = Batch_Settings__c.getInstance();

String deactivationEmails = batchSettings.DeactivatedUsersListemails__c;

// Apex batch code

Messaging.EmailFileAttachment csvAttc = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
```

.........

```
email.setToAddresses(deactivationEmails); // This is where the error is occuring
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Settoaddresses method accepts list of string and you are sending string as a parameter that's why it is failing